# Pseudo effect blur not working for the top part of section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a blur effect between a section with a linear animated gradient background and two other sections, and so far, the effect only works on the bottom part of the section, the upper half doesn't work.

```css
.featureSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-size: 400%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #5c2774, #335cc5, #637ffd);
  animation: bg-animation 7s infinite alternate;
  padding: 0% 2.5%;
  color: #f9faf8;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: unset;
  position: relative; 
}

.featureSection::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; 
  left: -50px; 
  right: -50px; 
  bottom: -40px; 
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(13px);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
}



.featureSection img{
  height: 17.5rem;
  width: auto;
  border: 25px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.6) ;
}

.featureSection h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: unset;
  font-family: SFBold;
}



#featureContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}
#featureContent h3{
  margin: 0;
}


#silicon, #motors, #driving{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 15px;;
  background-color: rgba(187,165,160, 0.2);
  text-align: end;

}

#motors {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<!--This is the first section-->
<section class="top">
<div class="logonav">
<img src="images/jplogo.svg" class="rotate" alt="">
<span id="NavText">
<h3>
   <a href="index.html"> M-IB:08</a>
</h3>


<div class="headerlinks">
    <a href="about.html" id="flat">About</a>
    <a href="https://www.ispr.gov.pk/" id="flat">Homebase</a>
    <a href="sourcecode.html" id="flat">Source Code</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.ispr.gov.pk/">Homebase</a></li>
        <li><a href="sourcecode.html">Source Code</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>

<div class = "firstsecmain">
<div class = "parawall hidden">
    <h2 class="hidden">Introducing, your new personal assistant!:</h2>
    <i class="hidden">M-IB:08</i>
    <p class="hidden">M-IB:08, the state of the art, AI Humanoid robot; designed and crafted to interact with the Homo Sapiens species. It may follow your demands, but perhaps not your protocols...
    </p>
    <a type="button" class="fbutton" href="purchase.html">Buy Now</a>
</div>

<img src="images/ibrahimfront.png" id="firstimg" class="hidden" alt="Main Picture of Muhammad Ibrahim">
</div>

</section>
<!--This is the second section-->

<section class="featureSection">
    <div id="featureContent">
        <div class="hidden rightfreeze" id="silicon">
            <img src="images/PIS SILICON.png" alt="">
            <span>
            <h3>Ultra-Fast S1 Silicon SOC</h3>
            <p>Introducing our S1 Silicon, an engineering masterpiece, ARM-powered, exclusive SOC, etched with a groundbreaking 1nm node process, giving it an industry-leading 74 trillion transistors. This computational powerhouse boasts up to <b>228 CPU cores</b>, a GPU with upto an astonishing <b>368 GPU cores</b>.<br> What truly sets S1 apart is its unimaginable <b>17,233 core Neural-Bionic Engine</b>, accelerating AI and machine learning tasks to new heights never dreamt of. Backed by cutting-edge DDR7 Hyperbionic memory and an NVMe v2 Gen XII Pro SSD, the S1 SOC is the heart of M-IB:08, enabling customers to experience AGI in an unparalled, dyanmic, and responsive way.</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden leftfreeze" id="motors">
            <img src="images/IbrahWorkout.jpg" alt="">
            <span>
            <h3>Military Grade, Ultra-Strong Steel Servo Motors</h3>
            <p>M-IB:08 is the epitome of sports prowess and robotic engineering excellence. With unparalleled physical capabilities. Equipped with <b>military-grade, steel servo motors</b>, capable of astonishing feats of <b>tensile strength</b>, endurance and durability. M-IB:08 can effortlessly carry up to a staggering, <b>4 tonnes</b> of weight, defying physics. It's extreme servos give M-IB:08 a insane sprint speed of <b>462 km/h</b>, that puts the viscious cheetahs and eagles to shame. M-IB:08 is not just a robot; it's a <b>symbol of innovation</b>, pushing the limits of what's possible in physics and showcasing the incredible potential of <b>human-machine collaboration</b>.</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden rightfreeze" id="driving">
            <img src="images/IbrahPolestarInside.jpg" alt="">
            <span>
            <h3>Bulit in, Full Self Driving Mode</h3>
            <p>M-IB:08 is an automotive <b>paradigm shift</b>, revolutionizing transportation with its unparalleled full self-driving prowess. Leveraging <b>state-of-the-art AI algorithms</b>, <b>advanced neural networks</b>, and <b>cutting-edge sensor fusion technology</b>, M-IB effortlessly assumes control of every conceivable vehicle archetype, rendering conventional driving <b>obsolete</b>. From <b>high-performance electric hypercars to rugged, gas-guzzling off-road titans</b>, M-IB:08's adaptive acumen remains unchallenged, heralding an era of <b>secure, efficient, and environmentally-conscious</b> mobility. Bid adieu to the steering wheel and embark on the future of transportation, with M-IB:08 as the <b>vanguard of the automotive renaissance</b>. You will never find yourself driving ever again.</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="sectiontwo">
    <h3 class="hidden">M-IB:08's Functions</h3>
    <div class="sectwocontent">
        <div id="overlaypic" class="hidden">
            <span id = "sidepair" class = "leftfreeze">
                <img src="images/ibrahside.png" alt="Ibrahim's Side picture" id="side">
                <p class="leftfreeze">M-IB:08 pairing and conversing with his customers</p>
            </span>
            
            <img src="images/gcpicibrah.png" class="" alt="Ibrahim's Group Picture" id="gc">

            <span id = ponderpair class="rightfreeze">
                <img src="images/ibrahpondering.jpg" class="rightfreeze" alt="Ibrahim Pondering" id="ponder">
                <p class="rightfreeze">M-IB:08 leveraging advanced neural network processing</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul class = "funclist" >
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 is much more advanced than ChatGPT!!!</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 possesses a strong understanding of GCSE Subject Specifications</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 can extensively handle Emotional Damage.</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 excels in sports and activities, posing great competition</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 is a natural teacher, and can help you with any quarrels or mishaps</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 is a good listener, and will extrapolate everything you need to let out</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 is a class rizzler, able to both figuratively and magnetically attract both humans and robots alike</a></li>
            <li class="hidden upfreeze"><a>M-IB:08 can consume a plethora of human food (including Apple Cores)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="sectionthree">
    
    <div class="sectthreecontent">
        <h4 class="quote hidden">"Don't forget, it's all about efficiency; and size is just a minor factor, just ask M-IB:08"</h4>
        <h6 class="quoteauthor hidden">- Drish Sanjay Bhatia, <br><i>PIS Chairman and Member of J&P Private Enterprises Board of Advisors</i></h6>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="quotetitles">
<h1 class="hidden leftfreeze">Here's what owners have said about their M-IB:08:</h1>
<div class="reviewsection">
    <section class="hidden rightfreeze" id="r1"><h3>"M-IB:08 is a friendly robot with low maintenance, he is also very intelligent and will solve math problems in a blink of an eye"</h3><p>-Rehan Salmani</p></section>
    <section class="hidden leftfreeze" id="r2"><h3>"M-IB:08 is very efficient and helps in any academic issues. He is definitely worth the price"</h3><p>-Pritika Bhalla</p></section>
    <section class="hidden rightfreeze" id="r3"><h3>"M-IB:08 has the moral compass of an Angel yet the intelligence of an elephant"</h3><p>-Rayan Akmal</p></section>
    <section class="hidden leftfreeze" id="r4"><h3>"M-IB:08 was programmed very well to be helpful, intelligent and most importantly patient"</h3><p>-Yusuf Alaswadi</p></section>
    <section class="hidden rightfreeze" id="r5"><h3>"M-IB:08 is a very intelligent machine, he is always willing to help others around him which makes him a very kind hearted robot!"</h3><p>-Haya AlMarri</p></section>
    <section class="hidden leftfreeze" id="r6"><h3>"M-IB:08 is always willing to help in all circumstances while trying to solve complex problems in maths”</h3><p>-Prisha Mehta</p></section>
    
</div>
</section>
<section class = "sectionfour">
    <div class="ctabut hidden">
        <div class="cta">
            <h5>What are you waiting for?!</h5>
            <p>Sign up for the PIS M-IB Newsletter for the latest development news on the M-IB project, and get special offers up to 20% off M-IB Accessories</p>
        </div>
        <a type="button" class="sbutton" href="signup.html">Sign up</a>
        </div>
</section>

<footer>
    <p>The Government of ROP - PIS Military &reg - All Rights Reserved - Created by Pathan - J&P Private Enterprises - V3.1</p>
</footer>
```

I tried messing around with before and after, but they both seem to want to only affect the bottom of the section.[bottom part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itsZ7.jpg),
[top part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qReYY.jpg)

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. When I run your code it seems to have a blur effect at both the top and the bottom like you want, but it does not match your screenshots. You must be leaving out some code from this question that is turning off the blur effect for you when you run it locally

Comment: that's bizzare. I will send the rest of the CSS code somewhere. Where would you want me to send it, for your convenience?

Comment: just  [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77075588/edit) and add enough code to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your code snippet reproduces the issue you are describing.  However... since the code you've posted doesn't have the issue it seems like you now have a pretty good idea of what is causing your issue and how to narrow it down